# Class file for org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, encoding, spring-security, basic-authentication

I've made a simple restAPI with Spring-boot and spring security, implementing Basic Authentication. I want to use inMemoryAuthentication, and bcryptPasswordEncoder, but for some reason my compiler is looking for the passwordEncoder in the wrong place, See title vs security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder.

My Basic auth looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;    
Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class BasicAuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
      // Authentication : User --> Roles
      // NoOpPasswordEncoder has been deprecated in Spring security so {noop} is being used to avoid errors
      protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
          .withUser("user1")
            .password("{noop}secret1")
            .roles("USER")
          .and().withUser("admin1")
            .password("{noop}secret1")
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
      }

      // Authorization : Role -> Access
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .httpBasic()
          .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/tokenservice/**")
              .hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/**")
              .hasRole("ADMIN")
          .and().csrf()
          .disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
          .and().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
      }
      @Bean
      public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
      }
    }
```

I get this error when trying to compile:

> Error:(21, 7) java: cannot access org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder
>     class file for org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder not found

Disregard the {noop} in front of the password. is there for testing without passwordEncoder.

I'm very new to Spring and gradle, and java all in all. Could i be using a wrong version of Spring? If thats the case, how do i fix it?

Comment: Hello ! Can you show us your dependencies in your gradle settings ?

Comment: dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
  compile('org.springframework:spring-oxm:4.1.5.RELEASE')
  compile('org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:1.3.3')
  compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.3.RELEASE')
  compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.2.3.RELEASE')
  compile('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1')
  testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

Comment: Your version seems to be good. Check my answer to see if it's resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your using latest **spring-security** version, you should find `PasswordEncoder` class in `org.springframework.security.crypto.password` package.

`PasswordEncoder` in package `org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder`  has been deprecated

Comment: Im using org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder. Or atleast im trying to. When i compile i get the error because its looking for the old one.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't a wrong import somewhere in your code ?

Comment: Cant find a single place where im importing org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder =/

Comment: And try to use spring-boot-starter-security instead of spring security dependencies : 
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')

Comment: That was it thank you! it compiles! Except now my "Encoded password does not look like bcrypt" when i try to post to the API. Have i misunderstood Basic Authentication tho? Does that mean i cant use bcrypt? does it have to be some standart encoding

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is caused by incompatible versions of spring-security-config (4.0.2.RELEASE) and spring-security-core (5.0.3.RELEASE)

The newer version of `spring-security-core` only accepts `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder`

I fixed this by downgrading `spring-security-core` to match `spring-security-config`.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to version mismatch in spring security config jar.

When you are upgrading your spring version from 4.x to 5.x , this issue occurs as PasswordEncoder class object is restricted in use.

In spring-security-config 4.x version in AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer the passwordEncoder() is overloading both the org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder and org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder, where else in spring-security-config 5.x it is only the org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder

spring-security-config 4.x

```
 public C passwordEncoder(org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder)
      {
        this.provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return this;
      }

      public C passwordEncoder(org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder)
      {
        this.provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return this;
      }
```

spring-security-config 5.x

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

  public C passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder)
  {
    this.provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    return this;
  }
```

Most probably solution is to downgrade your spring version to 4.x.